# JPA Entity Default Constructor Overwriting n-args Constructor

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I cannot initialize the entity object by a n-args constructor if there is a default constructor.
If I don't specifiy a default constructor I can initialize my object via a POST-Request. However since there is no default constructor, I can't GET an object. ()

Here is my code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "result")
public class Result {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name="term")
    private String term;
    
    
    @Column(name="hitsPerYear")
    private int[] hitsPerYear;
    
    @Column(name="year_begin")
    private int year_begin;
    
    @Column(name="year_end")
    private int year_end;
    
    public Result() {
        super();
        System.out.println("Default Constructor");
    }
    
    public Result(String term, int year_begin, int year_end, String key) {
        super();
        System.out.println("n-args constructor");
        this.term = "Some String to see if it works";
        this.year_begin = year_begin;
        this.year_end = year_end;
        int[] someTestArr = {1,2,3,4}
        this.hitsPerYear = someTestArr;
    }
        
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTerm() {
        return term;
    }
    public void setTerm(String term) {
        this.term = term;
    }

    
    public int[] getHitsPerYear() {
        return hitsPerYear;
    }


    public void setHitsPerYear(int[] hitsPerYear) {
        this.hitsPerYear = hitsPerYear;
    }
    
    public int getYear_begin() {
        return year_begin;
    }
    public void setYear_begin(int year_begin) {
        this.year_begin = year_begin;
    }
    public int getYear_end() {
        return year_end;
    }
    public void setYear_end(int year_end) {
        this.year_end = year_end;
    }

    

    
    
}
```

If I try to initialize an object of type result via a POST Request:

```
   {
        "term":"hello",
        "year_begin":2019,
        "year_end":2020,
        "key":"scraperapiKey"
    }
```

I get this response:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "term": "hello",
    "hitsPerYear": null,
    "year_begin": 2019,
    "year_end": 2020
}
```

And on the java console I can see that only the default constructor was called (sysout).

As far as I can remember, initialization via n-args constructor was always possible in jpa. Has this changed?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Hibernate.

Comment: Sorry, updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@JsonCreator
public Result(@JsonProperty("term") String term, @JsonProperty("year_begin") int year_begin, @JsonProperty("year_end") int year_end, @JsonProperty("key") String key) {
    this.term = term;
    this.year_begin = year_begin;
    this.year_end = year_end;
    this.key = key;
}
```